# Bad idea to redirect an assembly in an old project to a newer version? (Ie. Newtonsoft dll)

Tags: c#, json.net

Is it a bad idea to redirect to a newer version of the dll found in an old project? What are the chances that there are deprecated methods in the old that are no longer in the new? In my case, I would like to redirect Newtonsoft.dll v4 to v6 and am worried that there may be calls in the codebase somewhere that uses no longer existing methods, Is there a way to check? Thank you.

Comment: The way to check is to run the app.

Comment: The only reaosn you should redirect is if you can't upgrade to the newer package, in which case, you cannot check easily anyway, so you just have to ride your luck.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you will redirect old versions to new versions. Not the other way around. But the only way to verify it to try it.